# Сложный запрос UPDATE

Tags: запрос, sql

Необходимо обновить ячейку таблицы в БД ситуация осложняется тем что в таблице к одному id может быть несколько записей, а нужно лишь к одно из них.

Придумал такую штуку

```
UPDATE ".pref."iq_history  SET  hod='поле1'  WHERE ind=(SELECT MAX(ind) FROM tests_iq_history WHERE user_id='id_ пользователя'
```

но она не работает, позже прочитал что `UPDATE` не работает с внутренним селектом по той же таблице, советуют делать `INNER JOIN`, но я что то не могу покумекать как правильно сделать запрос..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас есть возможность добавить автоинкрементный PRIMARY KEY к вашей таблице tests_iq_history? Если да, то выборка бы упростилась

Если нет, то может разбить на 2 запроса?

```
maxId = SELECT MAX(ind) FROM tests_iq_history WHERE user_id='id_ пользователя';
UPDATE ".pref."iq_history SET hod='поле1' WHERE ind=maxId
```

Но, честно говоря, использование MAX на большом объеме данных будет крайне медленно. Вероятно, лучше переписать так:

```
maxId = SELECT ind FROM tests_iq_history WHERE user_id='id_ пользователя' ORDER BY ind DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Но тут надо быть осторожным, т.к. может использоваться файловая сортировка, поэтому надо экспериментировать с PRIMARY KEY/UNIQUE по нескольким полям

Comment: ind и есть автоинкрементный PRIMARY KEY, получается что у последнней добавленной строки с айди пользователя обновляется поле hod..

Comment: Раз он PRIMARY KEY, то чем вам этот вариант не подходит?

    // достаем последний id, сортировка будет идти по ключу, что быстрее, нежели MAX()
    maxId = SELECT ind FROM tests_iq_history WHERE user_id='id_ пользователя' ORDER BY ind DESC LIMIT 1;
    UPDATE ".pref."iq_history SET hod='поле1' WHERE ind=maxId

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать вложенный внутренний подзапрос.

```
UPDATE `".pref."iq_history` SET `hod`='поле1' WHERE `ind`=(SELECT `ind` from (SELECT MAX(`ind`) FROM `tests_iq_history` WHERE `user_id`='?')x);
```

или

```
UPDATE `".pref."iq_history` SET `hod`='поле1' WHERE `ind`=(SELECT `ind` from (SELECT `ind` FROM `tests_iq_history` WHERE `user_id`='?' ORDER BY `ind` DESC LIMIT 1)x);
```

Любопытно, что в разных версиях MySQL запросы выполняются по-разному. Поэтому стоит использовать `EXPLAIN` и при необходимости добавлять индексы. Для второго запроса, к примеру, `(user_id, ind)`.